# PEAR alternatives in other languages

Tags: c#, php, ruby, pear

Is there a good class repository like PEAR for PHP for other languages such as Ruby or C#? If so what are they?

Are they any good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For Ruby there is [rubygems](http://rubygems.org/) - the de-facto standard repository.
- For C# (.NET) - [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/) is your best shot I think.

Answer (score 3):

Perl has the [CPAN](http://cpan.org/) (possibly the best repository of reusable modules in the world).

Answer (score 2):

Ruby has its own package manager, [rubygems](http://rubygems.org/).  In addition, Ruby libraries can usually be found on either [RubyForge](http://rubyforge.org/) or [GitHub](http://github.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Python has the [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/), Haskell has the [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/hackage.html).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a thing in C# universe.

Maybe it's because in C# you can compile your binaries, which enhances interoperability.

If you need to find projects for csharp search for example google code, sourceforge, github or codeplex.

I don't know anything about ruby.